# Not able to get access token from salesforce

Tags: community, salesforce1-app, rest, java

I am getting authorization code and when i am trying to get the access token than it give error like

```
{
"error": "unsupported_grant_type"
"error_description": "grant type not supported"
}
```

This is my POST request,

```
POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type: authorization_code
client_id:3MVG9ZL0ppGP5UrB5oz4M4HieQ2tHjgz************CptuS5c
client_secret:49355154884444
redirect_uri:https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost/myapp
code:aPrxqJ8************dsdfsd8d45%3D%3D
```

But I am not able to get the access token.Can anyone help me please :)

Comment: Are you setting the grant_type, client_id, client_secret,redirect_uri and code inside the body or in headers? These need to be in the body of the request.

Comment: Yes, i m passing all the parameter in request body but then also it's not work.Help me please :)

Comment: I don't know which language you are using to make this post request, but if you are constructing the body, it should be something like code=aPrx....&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=XXXX etc.

Comment: i use java and i have all the required parameter to get the access token but still i m not able to get :(

Comment: Are you setting the required params in the format I mentioned above?

Comment: Yes I set all in correct way but now I am use OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow...Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

in the access token request you are adding `grant_type`. that is not required so remove that parameter and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Tushar, after removing grant_type i m getting same error and in sales force doc clearly said that this field is required...